# Looking for an affine curve not isomorphic to an affine plane curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to find an affine curve not isomorphic to an affine plane curve (as simple as possible). I am trying to find an affine curve $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^{n}_{k}$ such that its coordinate ring is not isomorphic to some $K$-algebra of the kind $K[x,y]/\mathfrak{a}$, but I cannot think in a curve like that.

I would appreciate if somebody could give me a hint, because I am really stuck in this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by $\dim_K A\leq 3$? I hope you do not mean vectorspace dimension. For example, $A=K[x,y]/(x)$ is the coordinate ring of the line in a plane. It is infinite dimensional over $K$.

Comment: @Mohan You are right, I have to think about it again. I will edit the question. Thank You.

Comment: It depends somewhat on what curve means here. One option would be to cook up a singular curve that has a tangent space of dimension $\geq 3$ at some point.

Comment: Dear @Hoot: I've done the cooking. *Bon appétit !*

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg My compliments to the chef!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy: just take an affine curve $C\subset \mathbb A^n_k$ whose Zariski tangent space at some point $p\in C$ has dimension $\operatorname {dim}_kT_pC=n\gt 2$.
The simplest example is to take for $p$ the origin $p=(0,0,\dots,0)$ on the image $C=f(\mathbb A^1_k)$ of the morphism $$f:\mathbb A^1_k\to \mathbb A^n_k: t\mapsto (t^n,t^{n+1},t^{n+2},\dots,t^{2n-1})$$
 This curve $C$ is not isomorphic to any affine subset of $\mathbb A^m_k$ for any $  m\lt n$.
[If you are stuck, check Shafarevich's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540548122), Chapter II,  pages 89-90, just after Theorem 2]